# System.Threading.Timer equivalent in PCL

Tags: c#, xamarin, timer, xamarin.ios, portable-class-library

***System.Threading.Timer*** is not available for PCL(Portable Class Library)

```
System.Threading.Timer tmr = new System.Threading.Timer(this.Method1,"Obj", 10000, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
```

I couldn't find anything equivalent in PCL.

I found something near to that

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(10000)
```

But this blocking the UI

while ***system.Threading.timer*** is not blocking the UI

Basically I want to call a method after a delay without blocking the UI from PCL

Kindly clarify this.

Comment: Why don't you just `await` it so that it doesn't block the UI? It's a Task, so it's *meant* to be awaited.

Comment: is there any other way I can do it ?

Comment: Try the this nuget as its is very close PCL port to System.Threading.Timer
`https://www.nuget.org/packages/Amoenus.PclTimer/`

Comment: @iamIcarus - I will give a try

Comment: @iamIcarus - Are you sure I can use it the same way ? like above

Comment: Its very similar yes , take a look at the example at `https://gitlab.com/motivated.it/Amoenus.PclTimer`

Answer (score 0):

You can start this:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(10000)
```

In a [background worker](https://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker). 
And if the timer is done you can give a feedback, so that you can call your function. 
This way will not block your UI...

Comment: Background worker is available for windows desktop app development I believe